NX Open Journal to list Element IDs for meshes in mesh collectors
I thought this would be the easiest thing in the world but for the life of me I can't figure it out.
I want to make a journal to automatically create a Group for every 2D Mesh Collector. So I figured I just need to go through all the mesh collectors, spit out the element IDs belonging to their meshes and boom add those to a group, easy. But I cannot figure out how to show the element IDs of the meshes in the collectors, I don't see anywhere in the documentation to do that. Is this possible? It must be possible. This is a .fem part, and I'm trying to make a python journal to do this. Any help would be most appreciated
